# Ink is not drawing over the Path using Inkcanvas UWP

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a Canvas element as Main UIElement, I have placed a Inkcanvas and path over the parent canvas.
When I try to draw ink over the path, its not working properly. It draws properly when it is drawn over the remaining space.

Note: Path is added as topmost child. I don't want to change the Zindex order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to change the z-index, maybe you just need to use `InkCanvas` as the top-level element:

```xml
<Canvas>
    <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
        <Path.Data>
            <!--data-->
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <InkCanvas />
</Canvas>
```